# Rails destroys upload on has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shrine

I have an organization model with an association `has_one :uploads, as: :uploadable`

It's a polymorphic relationship to

```
class Upload < ApplicationRecord
  include Uploaders::StandardUploader::Attachment.new(:file)
  belongs_to :uploadable, polymorphic: true, touch: true, optional: true
end
```

Everything works fine in terms of creating a record, but when I edit:

```
  = form.fields_for :upload, organization.upload do |form_upload|
    = form_upload.label :file
    = form_upload.file_field :file
      span Choose file...
```

The controller calls `build_upload` in the edit method, which builds a new association and actually destroys the existing one.

If I don't call `build_upload`, the form upload fiels are blank.

I'm at a loss of what's going on...what can I do to prevent the destroy on a `has_one` so the existing upload isn't lost?

What should I do to ensure the form fills in the existing upload?

Comment: You are using symbol not instance of the model. Just create new form for edit using instance `@uploader`

Comment: @7urkm3n please explain. You mean in the view where I'm calling `form_upload.file_field`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org) to allow associated records to be updated through the parent one:

```
class UploadableModel < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  accept_nested_attributes_for :upload
end
```

The `fields_for` should automatically generate the form fields in the nested attributes format ActiveRecord expects. See the examples in the [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-fields_for) API documentation below.

Comment: Thanks, Janko. You know what it was? I didn't have `reject_if: :all_blank` on that, so the form-updates were allowing the `:file` info to be nil'd...which in turn deleted the file (I think). I'm not sure if this is rails 5.1 specific. I'd like to update my question to be a little more clear. This is what I get for not stopping after 12 hours of coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting association like

```
has_one :uploads, as: :uploadable, autosave: false
```